# Windows Mobile 6 and webbrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, browser

I have a problem with Windows Mobile 6 and c#.
My scenario is this:

Project created with Windows Mobile 6 and vs2008 and framework 2.0 or framework 3.5.
My devive works with Internet explorer Mobile.

Problem:

With Framework 2.0: webbrowser works correctly (navegation and all javascripts), but my website opens in the right off screen and i don't can see website correctly.

With Framework 3.5: my screen from website opens correctly, but i lose all functionality
from website (javascripts for example).

Someone have some ideia for resolution this problem?

Comment: You may have to redesign the website to cater to your mobile device.

Comment: I'm working on it right now. But some funcionadalides site are not working.

Comment: Windows Mobile 6 is limited to IE3 or IE4, so your website has to be basic enough to support that far back. Some Javascript will work, but not much.

Comment: So I can emulate my website in another version of IE or another browser (Firexo, Opera, etc)?
I am working with the following product

http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-mobile-computer&cat=HSM&pid=Dolphin6500

Comment: Can I upgrade Internet Explorer Mobile? Or install another?

Comment: There were some people who used a mobile version of Opera for a while, but I have no idea where you'd find it. I would imagine Opera is newer, if it is still available.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Windows Mobile IE Version is 4.So you have got limited features of javascript (only in case of designs, ajax call will be working fine).

The better way is to design a css with Windows Mobile Screen's height and width, and apply it through out the web pages.

Comment: I solved a part of problem, upgrading my jquery library in website (works in Windows Mobile 6.5 Classic).
But i have problem with Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional, in IE browser my website works but in aplication no. 
The screen and ccs work, but no Javacript / jquery works.

I found it strange the contents of the request agent (Request.UserAgent) from this device:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible, MSIE 6.0, Windows CE; IEMobile 7:11)

Comment: Can u try with jquery mobile instead of jquery.I hope it will work.